# AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, access-violation

I'm getting this error when trying to reference a particular dll in my asp.net c# project (WaveLibMixer.dll).  Other users at my workplace do not experience this error running the exact same project with the same configurations so this leads me to suspect that it's something specific to my computer.

Target Platform is x64.  I wasn't getting this error before using Target Platform x86 or Any CPU but we need to target x64 because of the new SDK we are using.   I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate and Suppress JIT optimization is unchecked.  Also, I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and running visual studio as an admin.

I've gone through countless articles and forums and have tried all the suggested solutions but to no avail.  I would appreciate any help provided.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're running in to an issue with the platform specifics. If it worked under x86, but not x64, this could easily be the reason. The `IntPtr` data type in x86 is 4 bytes whereas in x64 it's 8 bytes. Try finding an x64 version of the .dll you're using. If your coworkers are using it, they should be able to just send it to you to include in the project.

Comment: The weird thing is that they are using the same version of the .dll that I'm using and their target platform for the project is also x64.  I took an exact copy of the project files from a co-worker's computer which is able to run the application without issue.  The cuprit dll (WaveLibMixer.dll) hasn't changed between this x64 version of the project and the previous x86 version.  The only thing that changed are the DLLs corresponding to the Speech Recognition SDK we are using (Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.SdkCore.dll and Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.dll)

Comment: I suggest that, you write an exe which use that dll, to make sure all the dll config is right.